# What is the proper response to いらっしゃいませ？

Tags: word-usage

The term is used in shops and stores to welcome customers. It seems impolite to ignore the greeting.

Comment: Showing our big smile should be more than sufficient.

Comment: I was gonna say a silent, mostly indirect head nod.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't impolite to ignore いらっしゃいませ and most Japanese don't respond to the greeting.

However if you want to respond to it, you may say こんにちは and give a shallow bow.